# How setMaxRows of jdbcTemplate works

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, jdbctemplate

I am trying to understand the way '`setMaxRows`' method of `JdbcTemplate` works.
Suppose I have a database table named '`employee`' which has 10 records.

I set maxRows to 5 using `JdbcTemplate.setMaxRows(5)`.

Now I do a select using following statement,

```
jdbcTemplate.queryForRowSet("select * from employee");
```

Above statement rightly returns 5 records, but when I have a look at the database logs the query executed there is "`select * from employee`", without any limit clause.

So after setting `maxRows` to 'n' does `jdbcTemplate` fecthes all records from '`employee`' table and then returns only 'n' rows. Or it fetches only 'n' records from database?

Comment: The truth is certainly in the database logs which means that this call will retrieve all employees returned by the db in whatever order the db finds applicable and selects the first 5.

Answer (score 2):

How the maximum number of rows is handled depends on the JDBC driver. The value of `maxRows` is eventually being set on the created `Statement` through the corresponding [`setMaxRows`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html#setMaxRows(int)) method. What your driver does with that is up to the driver.

The `JdbcTemplate` merely passes it on.